# Explain how this table is created angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I've searched at somewhere and found this code which I needed. I am working and wondering how this table is generated using angularjs. I mean I do not understand the process. I am confused in this `tdCells[primaryarray][tdCells[primaryarray].length] = i+1 ;` What it is used can someone help me figure it out

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller('check', function($scope) {
  $scope.totalSeats = 20;
  $scope.seatArr = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= $scope.totalSeats; i++) {
    $scope.seatArr.push(i);
  }

  console.log($scope.seatsArr);

  $scope.myData = [{
    seatno: '1',
    name: 'Melanie',
    ticketnNo: "abc456",
    insuranceNo: 34
  }, {
    seatno: '2',
    name: 'JOsefa',
    ticketnNo: "abc231",
    insuranceNo: 90
  }, {
    seatno: '17',
    name: 'Luna Marie',
    ticketnNo: "abc324",
    insuranceNo: 35
  }, {
    seatno: '5',
    name: 'Jana',
    ticketnNo: "abc221",
    insuranceNo: 91
  }, {
    seatno: '18',
    name: 'Scott Tooker',
    ticketnNo: "abc453",
    insuranceNo: 36
  }, {
    seatno: '6',
    name: 'Malanies Santos',
    ticketnNo: "abc241",
    insuranceNo: 93
  }, {
    seatno: '20',
    name: 'Luna Marie Landiola',
    ticketnNo: "abc322",
    insuranceNo: 39
  }, {
    seatno: '6',
    name: 'Eliza',
    ticketnNo: "abc222",
    insuranceNo: 92
  } ];
  
  $scope.getName = function(number){
      console.log(number);
      for(var i=0;i<$scope.myData.length;i++){
          if(number == $scope.myData[i].seatno)
              return $scope.myData[i].name;
      }
       return '';
  };
  var tdCells = [];
  var primaryarray=-1;
  for(var i=0;i<$scope.totalSeats;i++){
     if(i%3 ===0){
      ++primaryarray;          
      tdCells[primaryarray] = [];
     }
    
    tdCells[primaryarray][tdCells[primaryarray].length] = i+1 ;        
            tdCells[primaryarray][tdCells[primaryarray].length] = 
        $scope.getName(i+1);                  
  }
  $scope.rows = tdCells;
  console.log($scope.rows);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="check">
  <table border="1" width="100%">
    <colgroup span="7"></colgroup>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="tr in rows">
        <td ng-repeat="td in tr">
          {{ td }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </body>
```

Comment: http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2013/05/13/understanding-angularjs-directives-part1-ng-repeat-and-compile/

Comment: tdCells is an array of arrays. Each of the last cells will get the 0 based counter + 1 to make it 1 based then the new last cell will get the name also one based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the `$scope.getName(number)` function is simple, it gets the Name from your data array based on seat number.

The for loop later is somewhat tricky. What it does I think is:-

- It creates a Two Diamentional Array `tdCells` with three columns (`if(i%3===0)`)
- For each row in this 2D array `tdCells`:-

  - It sets the first element to seatnumber `tdCells[primaryarray][tdCells[primaryarray].length] = i+1 ;`
  - It sets the second element to name retrieved using the function `$scope.getName(...)` above. `tdCells[primaryarray][tdCells[primaryarray].length] = $scope.getName(i+1);`

In the ng-repeat it simply renders the 2D array in standard columns - just that each column becomes a couplet of seatnumber plus name.

HTH!